# Adjust microphone level on Safari mobile when using getUserMedia

Tags: javascript

I'm using javascript `getUserMedia()` to get access to the users microphone and record the audio with recorder.js

Everything is working fine except that the sound level is very low on mobile (Tested safari and chrome on IOS) but perfect on desktop (Chrome, FF, Safari).

I have tried to adjust the gain with `gainNode = audioContext.createGain();` and that will effect the level from 0.0 (no sound) to 1.0 (normal sound) or higher (distorted sound). Problem is that 1.0 i perfect on desktop but very very low on mobile. If i go to e.g. `gain=25` then the volume is much higher but also very distorted and therefore not useable.

Is it possible to get good and quality sound level on IOS and how?

**Here is my script so fare:**

```
var constraints = { audio: true, video:false }

navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraints).then(function(stream) {
        
        //Get mic input     
        audioContext = new AudioContext();
        gumStream = stream;
        input = audioContext.createMediaStreamSource(stream);

        //Set gain level
        gainNode = audioContext.createGain();
        gainNode.gain.value = 1.0;
        input.connect(gainNode);

        //Handle recording
        rec = new Recorder(gainNode);
        rec.record();

        //Audio visualizer
        analyser = audioContext.createAnalyser();
        freqs = new Uint8Array(analyser.frequencyBinCount);
        input.connect(analyser);
        requestAnimationFrame(visualize);

}).catch(function(err) {

});
```

**UPDATE:**

After a lot of research I found that the recording it self is fine. The problem is when i play the recorded audio without refreshing the browser the sound is very low. If i refresh the browser the sound is perfect.

What is really weird is if i write an `alert()` in my `stopRecording()` function, the sound plays perfect even without refreshing the browser.

Testet in IOS - Safari, could this be a IOS bug?

```
function stopRecording() {
    rec.stop();

    gumStream.getTracks().forEach(function(track) {
        if (track.readyState == 'live' && track.kind === 'audio'){
            track.stop();
        }
    });

    alert('Recording is complete');

    rec.exportWAV(handleRecording);
}
```

It's a bit like safari don't release or end the `getUserMedia()` and as long as that is 'on' the audio.play(); has low sound. Maybe the alert() changes browser focus and therefore it works(?)

I would really like to avoid having an alert there but don't know how this can be fixed.

Comment: Please, see my answer at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76083738/ios-safari-lowers-audio-playback-volume-when-mic-is-in-use. Starting from iOS 16.4.1 you are able to select Audio Session type.