# iOS Safari lowers audio playback volume when mic is in use

Tags: javascript, ios, safari, mobile-safari, web-audio-api

I have been trying to record and play an audio response coming from the server using web audio API. But when mic is in use or even stopped programmatically the playback volume is very low. It seems a feature of iPhone but it's really annoying when you are running a voice assistant like app in the browser. Here's what I tried using javascript:

```
stream.getTracks().forEach(track => track.stop()) // Mic muted but still volume is low
```

and

```
stream.forEach(function(track) {
    track.enabled = false; // Mic muted but still volume is low

});
```

Revoking mic permission works but it will be annoying when asking permission every time user trying to record. Is there any other efficient way to temporarily stop mic or regain the original playback volume?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Audio Session API

...probably is the best solution for you.

There are several audio session types for different purposes. Default value is `auto` and in your use case you probably want to set it to `play-and-record`, as it allows you to use both your mic and your speaker:

```
navigator.audioSession.type = 'play-and-record';
```

You can read it further here: https://w3c.github.io/audio-session/

Note: at the time of writing - Audio Session API is in an "Editor’s Draft" state, so you should check for that particular `navigator` property prior to rely on it. But it does work in Safari on iOS 16.4.1, though.

Comment: I checked in iOS 16.5 Public Beta and not working.

Comment: By saying "not working" you mean that you don't have the `audioSession` property of the `navigator` or that this particular line of code didn't solve your problem with the volume level?

Comment: That line didn't resolve the problem. I'm still working on it. Will update soon.

Comment: Try an example seen right here: https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=218012: The solution to this issue is to manually set the following BEFORE mic capture:

`navigator.audioSession.type = 'play-and-record';`

And then running the following AFTER mic capture

`navigator.audioSession.type = 'playback';`

Comment: Got it working as expected by setting `navigator.audioSession.type` to `transient` just before the playback, resetting it back to `auto` after the playback end playing two files in a row, where the first one contains 200ms of silence. Chaining audio with `Howler.js`.